# Why is \r\n appearing when I JSON encode an array

Tags: php, json, dom

I'm creating some arrays and turning them into JSON strings and I noticed something strange--some of the strings, 
when I JSON encode them, are getting \r\n added onto the front and end of the of the strings. 
The strings I'm encoding are pulled from HTML elements.

```
$arr = array(
    'licStat' => $rows2[13]->nodeValue, 
    'expDate' => dateReplace($data[5]->nodeValue), 
    'dicAct' => $rows2[11]->nodeValue
);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Expected output:

```
{"licStat":"Expired","expDate":"1999-12-20","dicAct":"Yes"}
```

Actual output:

```
{"licStat":"\r\n Expired\r\n ","expDate":"1999-12-20","dicAct":"\r\n Yes\r\n "}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `$rows2[13]->nodeValue` and `$rows2[11]->nodeValue` have carry return and line feeds in them.

You can use trim() to get rid of them:

```
$arr = array(
    'licStat' => trim($rows2[13]->nodeValue), 
    'expDate' => dateReplace($data[5]->nodeValue), 
    'dicAct' => trim($rows2[11]->nodeValue)
);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Thank you--the trim command was the answer. (I'm new the PHP in general--will accept your answer when the timelimit is up)

Comment: I'm glad I could help